# Python Flask serving static files from root static folder rather than blueprint's static folder

Tags: python, flask

I have a blueprint defined as :

```
auth_login = Blueprint('auth_login', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static', static_url_path='/static')
```

I am registering it as :

```
app.register_blueprint(auth_login, url_prefix='/user')
```

I have a route:

```
@auth_login.route('/<username>/')
def profile(username):
return render_template('profile/user.html',
username = username)
```

With this setup, the /user/ endpoint never manages to load the static files as I get,

"GET /user//static/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /user//static/css/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

What I really want is to look into the static folder of the root application and not the blueprint, so I want it to request

"GET /static/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Is it possible to configure this via static_folder or static_url_path so that the route will look for the static files at root and not relative to where the blueprint is mounted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Flask sets up the `/static` URL to serve files out of `{application_root}/static` - you are *overwriting* that default with your blueprint's code. (The URL is still `/static` but the folder is `{application_root}/path/to/blueprint/static`, which, by the sound of things, is not what you want).

Simply *remove* the `static_folder` and `static_url` arguments to your `Blueprint` initialization and the URLs should work just fine (assuming that you have the appropriate CSS in your `{application_root}/static` folder.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding. I tried removing the static_folder and static_url_path variables, but it is still making the request to "GET /user/<username>/static/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - instead of /static/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css, as if there was no difference. There is only one static folder in my whole application repo, and that is the static for the application. The blueprint code is at the same level as the static folder.

Comment: @AviDas - make sure that you are using at least path-absolute URLs for your static references: `<link href="static/css/some.css>` is path-relative while `<link href="/static/css/some.css>` is path-absolute (note the leading `/`).  Even better, use `{{ url_for('static', filename='/your/file.name') }}` so if you mount your application at a place that is not the URL root everything will *just work*.

Comment: @SienVieira that was the problem and I am going to accept your answer! Just curious, where might I find documentation for this behavior?

Comment: @AviDas - you'll want to look at [RFC 3968 Section 5](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5) for the rules regarding relative URL resolution.  The basics of it is that everything that a relative URL does not provide is provided by the context it is in, the path is merged if it is relative or used by itself if absolute, and everything after the relative part is used as-is.